# Is there any comprehensive way of hiding an app entirely with or without root access?

Tags: applications, root-access

By "comprehensive" I mean a method likely not easy to detect.

Is there any way to hide an app icon from any and every launcher?, it is not a problem if such a way requires root access installed. people around me are super geeks and theres little chances my methods will go unnoticed. I'm looking for a comprehensive solution to this problem so the usual "hide-app-from-launcher or change-its-icon or disable-this-app or use-an-app-to-hide-this-app" methods riddling the internet are ineffective for my situation.

To add context, I'm trying to install SSHDroid (an ssh-server) on my phone running Resurrection Remix with Magisk 15 and Nougat. the problem is I can't find a way to hide SSHDroid universally (I don't think there is any way to hide it from the Installed Applications list under Settings though). the server needs to be running day-in and `out without anyone noticing for my purposes.

Comment: Sure way would likely require root. If you are using Google launcher you can try this [Xposed module](P300QTL). Not verified

Comment: There is [this app too](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trigtech.privateme)

Comment: Why don't you use termux and set up a boot script to run sshd on start to create a ssh server?

Comment: @user218076 sshd binaries from SSHDroid have been working very well for me on all my devices, other servers are not as good.

Comment: I understand. I was just wondering if you can perhaps add the sshd binary file to your path, would propably need root or perhaps in /data/local. And have a init.d script start it, or use a file manager like FX to launch it. So that there is no app noticable on your device.

Comment: Errr... a running SSH server is noticeable by scanning the network. Don't even need to turn on the phone display to see it.

Comment: @derobert not if they're oblivious that I'm running sshd. The question is generalized, sshd was just my case.

Comment: @user218076 I haven't tried that yet. Will get back to you. Thanks.